# Using a varchar variable within an in clause TOAD SQL

Tags: sql, variables, plsql, toad

I have a lengthy query that has lots of repeated in statements set up with country locations like ('GB01','DE01','FR01') these are repeated 20+ times throughout the query. When these need to be amended it is straightforward but requires alot of changes.

I have made all the other parts that need changes into variables but cant seem to get anything to work for an in statement. I have recreated a smaller example here - Im aware for this example i could use a cursor / collections to acheive the same result but i dont believe a cursor/collections would work for my actual use case so would appreciate insight on how/if it can be made to work as part of an in statement returning a varaible.

```
SET FEEDBACK  ON;
set serveroutput on ;
DECLARE
    del_list   varchar(20); 
        BEGIN
    
   sELECT '''AU01'',''DE01'''     INTO del_list      FROM dual; dbms_output.put_line ('del_list: '||del_list);
    delete from kj_temp
    where loc in (to_char(del_list));
    commit;
    dbms_output.put_line ('records deleted: '||sql%rowcount);
    END;
```

If i run this my output shows:
del_list: 'AU01','DE01'
records deleted: 0
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

If i copy the del_list contents ('AU01','DE01') and run the script with this then all will work and 6 rows will be deleted.

Ive tried with/without the to_char and tried to do some searching but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about such an approach?

Sample table contains employees and their jobs:

```
SQL> create table test as select ename, job from emp;

Table created.

SQL> select job, count(*) from test group by job order by job;

JOB         COUNT(*)
--------- ----------
ANALYST            2
CLERK              3
MANAGER            3
PRESIDENT          2
SALESMAN           4
```

I'd like to *manipulate* certain jobs - clerks and managers so I'll store them into a collection. I'll use Oracle's built-in `sys.odcivarchar2list` (you can always declare your own, if you want). Then reference it in `where` clause. In this example, I'll delete those *clerks and managers*:

```
SQL> declare
  2    del_list sys.odcivarchar2list;
  3  begin
  4    del_list := sys.odcivarchar2list('CLERK', 'MANAGER');
  5
  6    delete from test
  7      where job in (select * from table(del_list));
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select job, count(*) from test group by job order by job;

JOB         COUNT(*)
--------- ----------
ANALYST            2
PRESIDENT          2
SALESMAN           4

SQL>
```

Right; no more clerks nor managers.

---

Alternatively, consider storing those values into a table. Then use it as a subquery in all your queries.

Comment: This is a perfect solution - I had not heard of sys.odcivarchar2list before, this works better than creating a table for me as i do not have priviledges for dynamic table creation in my prod system (Only in my Dev) but i can run this.
I did try to do  dbms_output.put_line ('del_list: '||del_list) but realised after reading up on the function that i cant really do that so simply removed.
Thanks